# Accept(Stream) returns HandshakeError::Interrupted(...), but if there is println!() then everything works

Tags: rust, websocket, server

I want to write a simple **non-blocking** single threaded websocket server. However, the `accept` function returns an error which I don't understand. Moreover, if you write `println!()` (where it is commented out), then the server starts working properly. What could be the problem, any ideas...

code:

```rust
use std::net::TcpListener;
use tungstenite::accept;

fn main() {
    let server = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    server.set_nonblocking(true).unwrap();
    for stream_res in server.incoming() {
        match stream_res {
            Ok(stream) => {
                //println!(""); //if you uncomment it works, why???
                match accept(stream) {
                    Ok(websocket) => {
                        println!("Accepted");
                    }
                    Err(err) => {
                        println!("Accept error: {:?}", err);
                    }
                }
            }

            Err(ref e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
                // some code
            }
            Err(ref e) => {
                panic!("{:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use crate: `tungstenite = "0.17.3"`

Comment: How do you define "non-blocking"? In my understanding, non-blocking and single threaded do not go well together. Do you plan to do other things and only occasionally check for new connections?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @MaxKlein, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpListener.html#method.set_nonblocking

Comment: @Jmb `HandshakeError::Interrupted(...)`

Comment: @Danila yeah, but what are you trying to achieve? The program is still never going to move past the for loop

Comment: @Danila and additionally (AFAIK) WebSockets are a kind of persistent connection. So as soon as one client (e.g. browser tab) is connected, the server is blocked and won't accept new connections until the client terminates the connection.